# unexpected end of stream; metadata expected

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, flacbox

I am trying to make an app in windows phone which do an audio steganography. to do this I convert FLAC stream to WAV stream so I could easily change data byte.

I compiled FlacBox as WP Class Library and remove `[Serializable]` since idk what to change it with.

```
public List<byte> ReadToEnd(System.IO.Stream streams)
{
    using (WaveOverFlacStream wav = new WaveOverFlacStream(new FlacReader(streams, false)))
    {
        try
        {
            long originalPosition = 0;

            if (wav.CanSeek)
            {
                originalPosition = wav.Position;
                wav.Position = 0;
            }

            try
            {
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

                int totalBytesRead = 0, bytesRead;
                if (wav.CanRead)
                    while ((bytesRead = wav.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
                    {// never pass this
                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                        if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
                        {
                            ...
```

wav only returned 44 bytes out of 19MB

`82,73,70,70,20,9,49,1,87,65,86,69,102,109,116,32,16,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,68,172,0,0,16,177,2,0,4,0,16,0,100,97,116,97,240,8,49,1`

I convert those bytes to ASCII and I got RIFF/WAVE headers but I still don't have audio data. what am I missing?.

edit: i use `[DataContract]` to change `[Serializable]` but still error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it would work if i read all byte from audio file then use `MemoryStream` to read those byte as `IO.Stream` then read those stream with `FlacReader` or `WaveOverFlacStream`